# Initialize variable as np array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

How do I transform a list into an numpy array? Is there a function that allows you to work on a list as if it were an array?

```
import numpy as np

container = [0,1,2,3,4]
container[container < 2] = 0
```

Returns:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: There are a lot of red flags here, but we don't have enough context to fully determine everything that's going wrong. What you describe should have worked, but such descriptions are unreliable. We need to see something that runs and reproduces the error when run.

Comment: Your edited code still doesn't run, because of that extra `)` on `self.values = v)`. With that parenthesis removed, [no exception occurs](https://ideone.com/vG9Wxi).

Comment: With the extra context, we can say more about some of the red flags - for example, `values` and `threshold` should be initialized inside `__init__` rather than at class level, and it looks like `values` should be taken as a constructor parameter rather than initialized to a nonsense value (the list) and set later.

Comment: I have lost the ability to ask questions. I am trying to update my previous posts to make them more helpful. Could you offer me guidance? To me, the post seems clear, now. I hope it does to you too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understand what you are looking for, but is it maybe [numpy.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

> **numpy.asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None)**
>
> Convert the input to an array.

you can then work with your former list as a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show a complete and working example so I modified your code a little bit. Basically, calling `np.array` should do what you need.

```
import numpy as np

class Container:
    def setValues(self,v):
        self.values = np.array(v)

    def setThreshold(self,t):
        self.threshold = t
        self.values[self.values < t] = -1

obj = Container()
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
obj.setValues(values)
obj.setThreshold(3)
print(obj.values)
```